# Projection clock: how to make a custom display?

Tags: character-lcd, appliances

I have a projection clock which projects a red image of the current time on the ceiling. I want to know if it's possible to find/build a similar display that would be computer-controlled (project arbitrary ascii content specified by a computer). What's different than a normal projector is that this thing doesn't need a very bright projector bulb or a fan - it's silent and on 24*7 and doesn't need expensive bulbs changed often (as a projector would). I want to use the same technology to project different text (I don't need images or high-res, just to control the text). What technology is it using - my web searches haven't turned up the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Most are just 7-segment LED displays with a lens. To show characters, just put 14-segment, 16-segment, or 5x7 dot matrix LED displays behind a similar lens.

Comment: Is that all - the normal LED displays are bright enough to be projected at that distance and be that bright - it's really just a lens and a standard LED display?? I was sure the power (brightness) requirements would mean something else is needed.  Also, anyone know what lens it is that can do that?